# Retuning a result as a string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I currently have the following query that gives me a result of `int(0)` How could I make it so I get a result of `0`?

**Code:**

```
public function check_manufacturer_id($manufacturer_id)
{
    $table  = $this->_table_products_manufacturers;
    $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT $table.id FROM $table WHERE $table.id = $manufacturer_id");
    $result = $query->num_rows();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Huh! Does `echo` spits `int(0)`?

Comment: are you dumping the result or echoing it?

Comment: Are you sure about using echo or print? Did you forget var_dump or print_r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the type casting before the variable name like this `return (string)$result;`

using your code:

```
public function check_manufacturer_id($manufacturer_id)
{
    $table  = $this->_table_products_manufacturers;
    $query  = $this->db->query("SELECT $table.id FROM $table WHERE $table.id = $manufacturer_id");
    $result = $query->num_rows();

    return (string)$result;
}
```